# 2 gridview in one scroll view

Tags: android, gridview

I have two gridview in one scroll view, however the only gridview to scroll is the pink one

[[image: please edit with the images]

and gridview 3 is fixed, but i want the two gridview to scroll together

how it looks like, i don't know if you can actually see... but when i scroll the page, only the pink gridview scrolls, and this vertical gridview doesn't
[[image: i tried to do it, but i don't have enough reputation]

and then it messes the numbers... 
my scrollview code:

```
  <!-- Items -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Content itself -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            >


            <GridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/grid_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
                android:numColumns="6"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                >
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Numbers -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="0dp"
                >

                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/grid_numbers"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:numColumns="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_vertical"
                    >
                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that gridview already have a scrollbar. Therefore, it "overrides" your scrollview behavior, and then the gridview 3 does not scroll.

You should consider using only one gridView.

Edit :
If for some reasons you don't want to, I'd suggest to overwrite "onTouch" functions in order to prevent grid 2 and 3 to catch the touch event, and therefore, allowing the scrollview to deal with it.
However, this approach may lead to further problems if you need to catch other behaviors (click, move, ...)